# Why is XCTestLog deprecated in Xcode 6.1.1 / IOS 8?

Tags: ios, xcode

Started using **cocoapods** and added **Specta** 0.2.1 for unit testing.  I have 3 warnings using the latest version that **XCTestLog** is deprecated.

**Xcode warnings**

```
.../Pods/Specta/src/SPTReporter.h
.../Pods/Specta/src/SPTReporter.h:3:26: 'XCTestLog' is deprecated
.../Pods/Specta/src/SPTXCTestCase.m
.../Pods/Specta/src/SPTXCTestCase.m:142:28: 'recordFailureInTest:withDescription:inFile:atLine:expected:' is deprecated
.../Pods/Specta/src/XCTestLog+Specta.m
.../Pods/Specta/src/XCTestLog+Specta.m:12:17: 'XCTestLog' is deprecated
```

I can't find anything specific - I figured StackOverflow may be able to generate some authoritative response.  Living with warnings causes me a small bit of personal madness.